# mod_rewrite to text/type/id

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, seo

My current code is something like this

```
store.php?storeid=12&page=3
```

and I'm looking to translate it to something like this

```
mysite.com/roberts-clothing-store/store/12/3
```

and something like this:

```
profile.php?userid=19
```

to

```
mysite.com/robert-ashcroft/user/19
```

I understand that it's best to have the SEO-friendly text as far left as possible, ie **not**

```
mysite.com/user/19/robert-ashcroft
```

(what stackoverflow does)

I can't figure out how to do this in apache's mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you may have to think "upside-down" with `mod_rewrite`.

The easiest way is that to make your **PHP emit the rewritten** `mysite.com/roberts-clothing-store/store/12/3` **links**.

**`mod_rewrite`** will then **proxy the request** to **one PHP page** for `rewrite.php?path=roberts-clothing-store/store/12/3` that will **decode the URL** and sets the arguments (here `storeid` and `page`)
 and **dynamically include** the correct **PHP file**, **or** just emit **301** for **renamed** pages.

A pure solution with `mod_rewrite` is possible, but **this one is much easier** to get right, especially when you don't master `mod_rewrite`.

The **main prob** could be with the **overhead** that might be significant but is the price of simplicity & flexibility. `mod_rewrite` is much faster

### Update:

The other posts **do** answer the question, but they don't solve the typical duplicate-content problem that avoided by having canonical urls (and using 301/404 for all those URLs that seems ok, but aren't).

Comment: any examples related to the Update ?

Answer (score 2):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/store/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ store.php?storeid=$1&page=$2 
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/user/([0-9]+)/ profile.php?userid=$1
```

But I wouldn’t use such URLs. They don’t make sense when you think of the URL path as a hierarchy and the path segments as their levels.

Answer (score 2):

Then you can just use RewriteRule directive in a .htaccess like:

```
RewriteRule roberts-clothing-store/store/(\d+)/(\d+)$ store.php?storeid=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html for help, or google.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^roberts-clothing-store/store/([^.]+)/([^.]+)$ store.php?id=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^robert-ashcroft/user/([^.]+)$ profile.php?userid=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to make the .htaccess as easy as possible and to do all the hard work in PHP:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ index.php?$1
```

This basically means to take everything and reroute it to my index.php file (in css/javascript/image directories I simply use "RewriteEngine off" to grand access to these files). In PHP I than just split("/", $param, 5) the string  and run a foreach() to check all the parameters. Encapsulated in a nice function this works fine for me.

**Update:**

For this easy case I highly recommend the use of explode() instead of using split(), because explode() doesn't come with the overhead by using regular expressions.

Comment: wouldn't this be much slower?

Comment: I don't know about the difference between splitting things in php with split/explode or using regular expressions in .htaccess, however the usage of mod_rewrite in general can slow things, but basically it all depends on your use case. In my experience with low traffic sites this doesn't matter at all. It's the huge images and database connections that are the big factors. Another thing is that solving problems in PHP is more flexible and clearer for all developers in my perspective.

Comment: I would add a RewriteCond so it only redirects when the targetted file does not exist (Don't remember the exact syntax right now). Then you still get the benefit of apache doing all the static file delivery (images, css, ...)