# apache url rewrite problem

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite

is it possible to rewrite the following URL:

http://dev.aurora.com/problem/getproblems/fieldset/2?search=false&rows=20&page=1

to

http://dev.aurora.com/problem/getproblems/fieldset/2/search/false/rows/20/page/1

Thanx in advance

Comment: See this similar question for approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024151/mod-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules in the .htaccess file in your document root directory:

```
RewriteRule ^problem/getproblems/fieldset/2/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)$ /problem/getproblems/fieldset/2/$3?$1=$2 [N,QSA]
RewriteRule ^problem/getproblems/fieldset/2/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ problem/getproblems/fieldset/2?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

The first rule is for the recursion and the second rule ends the recursion.

Comment: @Confusion: Yes, but that’s actually what they really want. They just say the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly; something like

```
^(.*)\?(search)=(.+)&(rows)=(.+)&(page)=(.+)$ $1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7
```

will work, but no matter whose answer you follow, you'll always need to tweak it to your situation, so you need to understand how it works.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_intro.html#regex,
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html and
something like http://civilolydnad.se/projects/rewriterule/ will get you a long way.